# Steps Query from 365 days ago into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, date

I am extracting the step data from health kit, in order to upload it to a website. The website takes in 365 integers and then allocates backwards dates to the website. So the first integer is today, second integer is tomorrow e.t.c.

I am attempting to create an array that will store 365 integers, it must be filled completely. I am using Healthkit to figure out the users steps from a year back, hence the array size. Every integer represents 1 day.

Using health kit I get dates and steps and null/nil from days with nothing on. So I was thinking about making some kind of if condition, where if date = date = current date then make a date + 1 day loop, but I'm not sure how to do this.

This is where I want to store the values so I can send them with JSON later one in another class.

```
// So this is the first array I am using in order to temporarily hold the arrays, not sure if this is the proper way. 

    struct stepy {
        static var step: [Int] = []
    }

// Second and final array that I will use to send the steps in JSON later on
    struct stepsofLastyears{
        var stepsOfLastYear:[Int] = []
    }


// Extracting the step data, irrelevant for my question, but added to add context

func todayTotalSteps () -> Void{
    let healthStore: HKHealthStore? = {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            return HKHealthStore()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.day = 1

    var anchorComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: NSDate() as Date)
    anchorComponents.hour = 0
    let anchorDate = calendar.date(from: anchorComponents)

    guard let stepsCount = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount) else {
        fatalError("*** Unable to create a step count type ***")
    }

    // Define 1-day intervals starting from 0:00
    let stepsQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepsCount, quantitySamplePredicate: nil, options: .cumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate!, intervalComponents: interval as DateComponents)

        stepsQuery.initialResultsHandler = {query, results, error in
                    let endDate = NSDate()
                    let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -365, to: endDate as Date, wrappingComponents: false)
                    if let myResults = results{
                        myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate as Date) { statistics, stop in
                            if let quantity = statistics.sumQuantity(){
                                let date = statistics.startDate
                                let steps = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                                // Here is where I attempt to enter the steps into the array
                                stepy.step.append(Int(steps))
    // Here I attempt to fill the second array with 0 for the dates that are null, I was thinking to add the date if check here to place the step value on the correct corresponding value in the array. 
                                stepsofLastyears.stepsOfLastYear = Array(repeating: 0, count: 365)
                                    .enumerated()
                                    .map{ index, value in
                                        guard stepy.step.indices.contains(index)else {return value}
                                        return stepy.step[index]}

                                print("\(date): steps = \(steps)")

                                //NOTE: If you are going to update the UI do it in the main thread
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    //update UI components
                                }
                            }
                        } //end block
                    } //end if leta
                }
                healthStore?.execute(stepsQuery)
```

The data I get look like this

```
2017-05-02 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 5544.0
2017-06-02 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 844.0
2017-09-02 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 9999.0
2017-10-02 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 5640.0
2017-10-11 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 6210.0
2017-10-12 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 423.0
2017-10-13 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 555.0
2017-10-14 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 42847.0
2017-10-15 22:00:00 +0000: steps = 555.0
```

I want to take the step data and put it into an array, and make the first value of the array represent today, the second tomorrow. E.t.c

Comment: First tip: add comments to your code, explaining what each line is supposed to be doing. Makes it much, much easier for someone else to try and help.

Comment: Edited and added comments for clarity

Comment: ok - you said you get *"null/nil from days with nothing"* ... so, when you do `myResults.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!...`, do you end up with 365 elements? Some that have "step" values, and some that are nil, but you have the full set of 365 days of data?

Comment: Not sure what you mean Donmag, but I edited into the data I get and what I want to do with it in the main post

Comment: can you show your `stepsQuery` so I can try and see what's going on? (for future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: I added the entire function, not sure if it is relevant though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158616/discussion-between-donmag-and-jsondork).